# how to detect window is loaded in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, window

I have been trying to solve this problem for a couple days but can't seem to get it to work.

First, I have a custom hook to get if the client is viewing in mobile or desktop format.

that looks like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function getWindowDimensions() {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
    console.log("defined");
    console.log(width < 768);
    return width < 768 ? true : false;
  }
  console.log("undefined");
  return true;
}

export default function useWindowDimensions() {
  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(
    getWindowDimensions()
  );
  function handleResize() {
    setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowDimensions;
}
```

Now I am trying to use this in order to switch between a footer or a header style interaction on my website:

```
import useWindowDimensions from "hooks/useWindowDimensions";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Header from "./Header";

export default function Shim(props) {
  const isMobile = useWindowDimensions();

  return (
    <div>
      {!isMobile && <Header {...props} />}
      {isMobile && <Footer {...props} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I expected this to work perfectly, however it looks as if the the initial value is getting set when typeof window === "undefined", so, the mobile view is rendered in desktop size (if I resize the window after the site is loaded, it works as expected.) Would anyone be willing to lend me a hand as to how to get this to work appropriately?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I solve same problem with this context api hook.

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const SizeContext = createContext();

const SizeContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
    const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(true);
    const [isDesktop, setIsDesktop] = useState(true);

    function debounce(fn, ms) {
        let timer;
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                timer = null;
                fn.apply(this, arguments);
            }, ms);
        };
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const debouncedHandleResize = debounce(() => {
            setWidth(window.innerWidth);
        }, 0);

        window.addEventListener('resize', debouncedHandleResize);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', debouncedHandleResize);
        };
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (width <= 575) {
            setIsMobile(true);
            setIsDesktop(false);
        } else if (width >= 576 && width < 767) {
            setIsMobile(true);
            setIsDesktop(false);
        } else if (width >= 768 && width < 991) {
            setIsMobile(false);
            setIsDesktop(true);
        } else if (width >= 992 && width < 1199) {
            setIsMobile(false);
            setIsDesktop(true);
        } else {
            setIsMobile(false);
            setIsDesktop(true);
        }
    }, [width]);

    return (
        <SizeContext.Provider value={{ width, isDesktop, isMobile }}>
            {children}
        </SizeContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useSizeContext = () => useContext(SizeContext);

export default SizeContextProvider;
```

import context api use any component.

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <SizeContextProvider>
      <Device />
    </SizeContextProvider>
  )
}
```

Here Device Component use Context Api

```js
const Device = () => {
    const { isMobile, isDesktop } = useSizeContext();

    return (
        <div>
            {isMobile && <h1> Small Device </h1>}
            {isDesktop && <h1> Largest Device </h1>}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am currently getting this error response with your setup:

`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'children' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
  3 | export const SizeContext = createContext();
  4 | 
> 5 | const SizeContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    |                               ^
  6 |   const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  7 |   const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(true);
  8 |   const [isDesktop, setIsDesktop] = useState(true);`

do you have any advice on how to fix that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm forget to wrap context api that it show error.
please follow this code . please wrap context api app.js and use your component
```js
<SizeContextProvider>
      <ComponentHere />
    </SizeContextProvider>
```
Now It work.

Comment: Gotcha. Now the only problem is that I am getting a "window is not defined error". so I added a typeof window === "undefined" ? 1500 : window.innerHeight on the width line, and this fixed that. Is that a solution you would recommend? Thanks a ton!